# httpclient + javascript

Tags: javascript, httpclient, rhino

I am using Apache Httpclient and I need to use a Javascript engine to run the script for the page. Similar to a small web browser. Does anybody know a way to integrate javascript with httpclient and send a request back to the original server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/