# Simulating Mobile Web Browser from java program

Tags: java, browser, mobile

I am trying to load a mobile version of the web page using a java program for extracting few information from the web page, easily.

In Firefox, after adding the user agent switcher plugin, i have added a new user agent with the value

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.2; U; Series60/3.1 NokiaE71-1/110.07.127; Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413"
```

After this, if i try to load http://www.bbc.co.uk/, the mobile version of the web page is loaded successfully.

But i am trying to do the same with a java program using apache httpclient library by setting the `User-Agent` as given below:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(httpclient.getParams(),
  "Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.2; U; Series60/3.1 NokiaE71-1/110.07.127; Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413");
```

But i am not getting the mobile version of the the same link.

I hope the redirect will happen automatically here and i will be getting the mobile version of the page as the user-agent is modified.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Enable HttpClient logging (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) and post results.

Comment: Now i found that the problem is there with the sites which sets the window.location for redirecting the web page in the response.. somehow the apache httpclient-4.1.3 is not handling this parameter automatically even after setting the redirects HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) does not support [JavaScript redirection](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php).

> Please note that HttpClient is not a browser. Importantly it lacks UI, cache, HTML renderer and a JavaScript engine. To learn more about the scope of HttpClient please refer to HttpClient Primer

Maybe you can try solutions proposed in these questions

- [httpclient + javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587389/httpclient-javascript)
- [Apache HttpClient 4 And JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260282/apache-httpclient-4-and-javascript)
- [JavaScript Context in HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597441/javascript-context-in-httpclient)

Comment: Thanks.. i started using HtmlUnit now and it handles java script redirection perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Had you setFollowRedirects on HttpClient?

Comment: Hi, i have set the parameter 'http.protocol.handle-redirects' to 'true' as setFollowRedirects is not supported by HttpGet method in HttpClient 4.0.